# How to read an external file data in xml through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that reads data externally from HTML file.

XML File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test.xsl"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <external><![CDATA[2F434A1.htm]]></external>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <external><![CDATA[2F434A1.htm]]></external>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>External</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="external"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The data to be printed is available in the html file, When we open this xml we get name of the html file rather the data.

Please provide us suggestion how to get data to be displayed in XSLT referenced xml.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `iframe` e.g.

```
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><iframe src="{external}"/></td>
  </tr>
```

Of course that delegates the task of rendering and including the HTML document to the browser that shows the HTML your XSLT creates. But XSLT has no way to include an HTML document, unless you know it is well-formed XHTML, in that case you could use

```
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:copy-of select="document(external)//body/node()"/></td>
  </tr>
```